# Replace value of text field and display it in another text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert text first text field value entered in inr to cad but i am unable to do so, 
suppose for example:
if the text entered in first field is 1000 the it should display 20 in text field two
i have tried something like this

```
<label>Price</label>

    <input id="price_inr" name="price_inr" type="text" class="validate" required placeholder="Price in INR"  /> 
    <input id="price_cad" name="price_cad" type="text" class="validate" required readonly="readonly" placeholder="Price in CAD" />
    <!-- Script coverts INR to CAD -->
    <script>
        $('#price_inr').change(function() {
        $('#price_cad').val($(this).val());
        });
        $("#price_cad").on("change", function() {
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace(price_cad.value, price_cad.value/50);
         });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: what is `price_cad` in  `return value.replace(price_cad.value, price_cad.value/50);`?

Comment: I have done so but its not working, may be i have written something wrong, can you please tell me how to do so as i am new with jq

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use two `change` events, you can do this in one step.

```
$('#price_inr').change(function () {
    $('#price_cad').val($(this).val() / 50);
});
```

Don't forget to add prover validation to the first input field which checks if entered values is a valid number.

One more thing to note here is that `change` will be triggered when input looses focus. You can try using `keyup` instead, maybe it will better fit your requirements.

Best of luck.

Comment: You are welcome. Please don't forget to mark the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine using jquery 1.11.

The second part `$("#price_cad").on("change", function()` will not work because of the "readonly" attribute.

Changing it and editing will allow change back and forth

```js
$('#price_inr').change(function() {
  $('#price_cad').val($(this).val());
});

$("#price_cad").change(function() {
  $('#price_inr').val($(this).val()/50);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Price</label>

    <input id="price_inr" name="price_inr" type="text" class="validate" required placeholder="Price in INR"  /> 
    <input id="price_cad" name="price_cad" type="text" class="validate" required  placeholder="Price in CAD" />
```